# CSS - change the color of a text dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to `CSS` and `AngularJs`. I am using text-angular in which I am showing a html file.In that based upon some rules I have some words from that html which needs to be highlighted. I have previous and next click functionality where when I click next it auto-focus the next word and highlight it. So, I want to highlight all the words every-time . But only the word which is now in focus should be in a different color.My code is -

```
mark, .mark {
    background-color: #FFEB3B;
    padding: .2em;
}
$scope.highlight_AutoFocusOrphan = function() {
    uploadService.getDocumentAsHTML($scope.documentType, uploadService.currentFileName)
        .then(function(data) {
            $rootScope.data.htmlDocument = $scope.highlightHTML(data, $scope.orphanData.orphanText);
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.editorScope = textAngularManager.retrieveEditor('editor1').scope;
                var element = $scope.editorScope.displayElements.text;
                if (element != null) {
                    element[0].querySelector('.mark').focus();
                    angular.forEach(uploadService.getOrphans(), function(orphan) {
                        //if (first_iteration) {
                        $rootScope.data.htmlDocument = $scope.highlightHTML($rootScope.data.htmlDocument, orphan.attributes.text);
                        first_iteration = false;
                        // }
                    });
                }
            });
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.errorMessage = error.status + " : " + error.statusText;
            toastr.error($scope.errorMessage, 'Error : ' + error.status);
            if (error.status === 401) {
                loginService.authenticationError();
            }
        })
        .finally(function() {
            $scope.fetchingDocumentAsHTML = false;
        });
};
$scope.highlightHTML = function(content, text, className, notByWordBoundry) {
    var RegExpEscapeText, str;
    if (!(content && content.replace)) {
        return '';
    }
    if (!text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
    }
    if (!className) {
        className = 'mark';
    }
    RegExpEscapeText = text.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
    if (!notByWordBoundry) {
        str = new RegExp('(\\b)' + RegExpEscapeText + '(\\b)', 'gi');
    } else {
        str = new RegExp(RegExpEscapeText, 'gi');
    }
    return content.replace(str, '<span tabindex="1" class="' + className + '">$&</span>');
};
```

I have tried Different solutions.But I was not able to resolve it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you seeing any error in console

Comment: No error in console.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpfull. Try something with jQuery:
View on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oj3mqyqv/)

```
$(function () {
    var $item = $('.box .box-item'),
    radnomColor = ["red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "brown", "gray", "orange"],
    blueSpec = ["#82bdff", "#447bb7", "#224f80", "#1571d6", "#6237f7", "#9d81ff"];

    $.each($item, function (j, m) {
        var $wrap = $(this).parent();
        if ($wrap.hasClass('colorScale')) {
            var colorIndex = j < radnomColor.length ? j : (j - (radnomColor.length * parseInt(j / radnomColor.length)));
            $(m).css("color", radnomColor[colorIndex]);
        }
        if ($wrap.hasClass('blueScale')) {
            var colorIndex = j < blueSpec.length ? j : (j - (blueSpec.length * parseInt(j / blueSpec.length)));
            $(m).css("color", blueSpec[colorIndex]);
        }
    });
})
```

And combine with markup:

```
<h2>
     Random color scheme
    </h2>
   <div class="box colorScale">
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h2>
     Blue color scheme
    </h2>
    <div class="box blueScale">
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
        <div class="box-item">
            This is random "green" colored scheme
        </div>
    </div>
```